# Export Sqoop fields with enclosure and/or delimiter character inside

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

I'm trying to export this type of data in PostgreSQL

```
"WIFI:S:FIBRA-3;T:WPA;P:YOdfdgg4677;;";"2021-05-18 14:31:34"
"'":.56#!:&7:&":8";"2021-05-19 15:56:22"
```

but I am not able to recognize the first field correctly, I think because of the double quotes.
The command that I'm using is:

```
export \
    --connect $DB_JDBC_URL_MAIN \
    --username=$DB_USER \
    --password="$DB_PASSWORD" \
    --table "$DB_SCHEMA.$DB_TABLE" \
    --export-dir $EXPORT_DIR \
    --input-lines-terminated-by '\n' \
    --input-fields-terminated-by ';' \
    --input-null-string 'N/A' \
    --optionally-enclosed-by '\"' \
    --escaped-by \\ \
```

I hope you can help me.

Comment: The `optionally-enclosed-by` should handle the quotes, although, I dont see why you need a backslash... And your second row fields aren't terminated by semi-colons

Comment: If I'm not wrong, the last field doesn't need to have `input-fields-terminated-by`, but it should be `input-lines-terminated-by`, right?
Regarding the backslash, you are right, I have removed it but it still does not recognize the field well.

Comment: Line endings are new-lines. Those are fine. The fields in each line ought to be consistent as well, and the first line is using semicolons

Comment: Oh sorry, that was a typo error, all my data is with semicolon